# DataTable render doesn't work when <td data-order="1"> is added

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, datatables

I have the following minimal example using a function `commaSeparateNumber()`

It worked well before adding `data-order="..."`. After adding it for sorting reasons, it no longer displays `4000` as `4,000` etc.

What could be the issue? I've tried to only apply render on `type === 'display'` to no avail.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: [1],
        render: function(data, type, row) {
         
            return commaSeparateNumber(data); 
        },
      },
    ],

  });
  
  function commaSeparateNumber(value) {
    let newvalue = value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    //console.log(newvalue); //this does work. It return 4,000... etc.
    return newvalue;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-1.13.6/fc-4.3.0/fh-3.4.0/r-2.5.0/sc-2.2.0/sl-1.7.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-1.13.6/fc-4.3.0/fh-3.4.0/r-2.5.0/sc-2.2.0/sl-1.7.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>file1</td>
          <td data-order="4000">4000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file2</td>
          <td data-order="5000">5000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file3</td>
          <td data-order="60000">60000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file4</td>
          <td data-order="300000">300000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file5</td>
          <td data-order="1000000">1000000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file6</td>
          <td data-order="1000000">20000000</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the commaSeparateNumber function to format the numbers with commas for display. However, when this renderer is used for sorting, it's treating the formatted string with commas as the sorting value, which leads to incorrect sorting behavior.

You can use this parameter to conditionally apply the formatting only when the type is 'display' and leave the sorting value untouched.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: [1],
        render: function(data, type, row) {
          if (type === 'display') {
            return commaSeparateNumber(data);
          }
          return data; // For sorting, return the original data without formatting.
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  function commaSeparateNumber(value) {
    return value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-1.13.6/fc-4.3.0/fh-3.4.0/r-2.5.0/sc-2.2.0/sl-1.7.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-1.13.6/fc-4.3.0/fh-3.4.0/r-2.5.0/sc-2.2.0/sl-1.7.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>file1</td>
          <td data-order="4000">4000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file2</td>
          <td data-order="5000">5000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file3</td>
          <td data-order="60000">60000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file4</td>
          <td data-order="300000">300000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file5</td>
          <td data-order="1000000">1000000</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>file6</td>
          <td data-order="1000000">20000000</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your example doesn't produce the result I'm looking for `4000` should appear as `4,000`. I don't have issues with the sorting. Only with the appearance.